# How to animate opacity of image for a background of a grid but NOT the controls in the grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want my background image to animate opacity, but NOT the controls "overlayed" on top of it.  Here's my working XAML, but currently the controls (combobox etc) also fade in and out with the image.  How do i change it so the controls don't change as well?

```
<Window x:Class="george.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/George_mcfly.jpg" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.8" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"></DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.3"  AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"></DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding ApplicationName}" FontSize="18" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Label Content="Version:" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Version}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

            <Label Content="Current Connection:" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="example" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>

            <ComboBox Grid.Row="3">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="A" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="B" />
            </ComboBox>
            <Label Content="User Name: " Grid.Row="4" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="sample text" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>

            <Label Content="Active Directory Groups: " Grid.Row="5" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <ListBox  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <ListBoxItem Content="1" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="2" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="3" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="4" />
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detach that parent-child relationship which is pretty simple since you already have it embedded in a Grid;

```
    <Window x:Class="george.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border>
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/George_mcfly.jpg" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0.8" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"></DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0.3"  AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"></DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
<!-- We end the Border so it's only behind the elements instead of acting as their parent -->
            </Border>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding ApplicationName}" FontSize="18" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <Label Content="Version:" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Version}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <Label Content="Current Connection:" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label Content="example" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <ComboBox Grid.Row="3">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="A" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="B" />
                </ComboBox>
                <Label Content="User Name: " Grid.Row="4" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label Content="sample text" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <Label Content="Active Directory Groups: " Grid.Row="5" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <ListBox  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <ListBoxItem Content="1" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="2" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="3" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="4" />
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Oh and +1 for the McFly, where's Marty and the doc? :)

Oh and also, you might consider attaching those events to the parent grid and targeting just the Border in the animations with `TargetName` or `TargetObject` since as you have it now, only the Border will do it.

Comment: Doc was 2 versions ago, Lorraine is the current version.  Haven't got to Marty yet.  I'm trying your suggestion now, thanks...

Comment: lol BiFF was the beta.  (Billing information and Financial Forecasting).  I will have to remember to add Needles to the upcoming release schedule, thanks!